# Cannot Access ViewModel in DialogFragment

Tags: android-studio, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to retrive dates from database using using month and year in **Dialog Fragment**. But the problem is it is showing error while executing.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.untolddiary, PID: 21823
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getViewModelStore(Fragment.java:414)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.<init>(ViewModelProvider.kt:118)
        at com.example.untolddiary.CalenderFragment.<init>(CalenderFragment.kt:46)
        at com.example.untolddiary.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$2(MainActivity.kt:111)
        at com.example.untolddiary.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$JiX3NTZFHpQbKFS4nkkCvOkq6Q8(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.untolddiary.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7766)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7739)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:860)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29330)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8306)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
```

**Dialog Fragment**

```
class CalenderFragment : DialogFragment() { 

private val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DViewModel::class.java)

private fun setMonthView() {
var calenderHighlighter = CalenderHighlighter()
calenderHighlighter.positionsList(viewModel.retrivePositions(MonthSeperator(selectedDate!!)!!.toInt()
            , YearSeperator(selectedDate!!)!!.toInt()))
   }

}
```

Comment: This is happening because you are trying to access the viewMode before the fragment has finished being created and attached. Try putting the "private val viewModel = ..."  into the onCreate method of the dialog fragment of the and call the "setMonthView()" from the onCreateDialog" method.

Comment: But i solved that error in another way, still Thanks

Answer (score -1):

use view model provider factory class